# ILookUp vs. Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

Are the following data structures **almost** same ?

```
ILookup<int, string>  vs.  Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>
```

Comment: Yes they would be similar / same.  But ILookup is an interface.

Comment: The main difference is in the implementation: the current default Lookup (created with `ToLookup()`) implementation of the item indexer `[]` will return an empty enumeration if the key is not found, where a dictionary will throw an exception. Of course since ILookup is an interface, it's up to the implementation how this is handled.